# How to check if a string contains a given string using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Use this Code to check a char is contain in string if true checked checkbox but it always return true.why??

```
//it is mvc project and after execution it become like this:if ($("123:contains(1)"))
if ($("@Model.VillageAR.IncomeLocation.ToString():contains(1)")) 
{
    $('#IncomeLocation1').attr('checked', true);
}
```

Comment: String manipulations have nothing to do with jQuery...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're really just looking for [**indexOf**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```
if ( "@Model.VillageAR.IncomeLocation.ToString()".indexOf('1') != -1 ) {
    $('#IncomeLocation1').prop('checked', true);
}
```